# Removing data spikes in the most time efficient way possible

Tags: python, pandas

My result is that using pandas.DataFrame.mask() you get impressive time efficiency, but with that method so far i'm not being able to remove all spikes, especially below total average ones. What I'm trying to do is to set to 'NaN' all instances that are over/below 20% from the current iteration value, I'm removing a lot of noise but some is still there.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')


price = df['Price']
price.mask(price.diff(-1) >= 0.2 * price, inplace = True)
price.mask(price.diff(-1) <= -0.2 * price, inplace = True)
```

Unfortunatelly the code above works just fine with small data so I'm not able give a more precise example but you can see a picture of the results here:
[image]

Can someone point obvious mistakes of my strategy that I failed to see or suggest a complete different approach that would work in a time efficient way?

Comment: I would check if the spikes are not actually a short sequence of deviating values. Your mask will then remove the first rise or fall value, but then will keep the other deviating values. If this is the case you are also masking some legitimate data after the values returns to the baseline.

Comment: @Aguy, makes sense, but even using 0.1% margin instead, there are still spikes that are scattered somewhat in the sameway as 20%. Maybe it's bad data?

Comment: Not sure why the margin should make a difference. It's the sequence length that matters. Your code can remove spikes only if the are one item wide.